# How to name Span in Spring Sleuth in a reactive calling chaining

Tags: java, spring-cloud, project-reactor, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have Spring Cloud Sleuth (2.0.2.RELEASE) working within a (partially) reactive class in some web based request/response system. The code is something like this:

```
private static final Scheduler PROCESSING_SCHEDULER = Schedulers.newParallel("processingScheduler");

public Set<ProcessedItem> processItems(List<Item> incomingItems) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(incomingItems)
        .publishOn(PROCESSING_SCHEDULER)
        .collectMultimap(Item::getRequestIdentifier)
        .flatMapIterable(Map::values)
        .flatMap(itemProcessor::processGroupedItems)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        .block();
}
```

As there are quite many responses coming in all the time, this method is being called several hundreds of times for one single request.
I suspect that this call with the `.publishOn` leads to hundreds and thousands of `async` spans in Zipkin (see attached screenshot). At least I assume that the spans are from that because it is what I understand from [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.0.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_naming_spans)

So my first question would be:
How can I associate a name for such async threads? I don't have a place to put `@SpanName` here.

As a follow up, is there any way to NOT collect these spans? I don't need them, they fill up our Zipkin storage, but I also don't want to disable reactive or Sleuth in general since it is needed in other places ...

[Screenshot from Zipkin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLeaf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom `SpanAdjuster` that will modify the span name. You can also use `FinishedSpanHandler` to operate on finished spans to tweak them.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen `SpanAdjuster` but didn't find the `FinishedSpanHandler`. I will give it a try!